# GWT [Error] Rebind result 'com.viktor.MyClassJSO' cannot be a JSO

Tags: java, gwt

after upgrading from GWT 2.6. to 2.8 stable version, I've started getting this error during compilation.
The MyClassJSO is just plain JSO class (extends JavaScriptObject), so I really don't know where the problem is.

**Does anyone know what does this error exactly mean?**

I've managed to change logging level to more verbose one, but no further info appears.

Thanks for all answers.

Comment: This error can be triggered in case you create a JSO using `new` in Java. Apparently there was a bug in GWT 2.6 which made that possible but since 2.7 the above error is raised in this case.

Comment: You should read about [JsInterop](https://docs.google.com/document/d/10fmlEYIHcyead_4R1S5wKGs1t2I7Fnp_PaNaa7XTEk0/). In GWT 2.8 it is the preferred way of interacting with JavaScript.

Comment: I'm using GWT.create. 
The call where it fails : 
`someMethodCall((MyClassJSO) GWT.create(MyClassJSO.class));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't create a JSO with `GWT.create(...)` (nor can you generate JSO types). The only way is to create the instance in JSNI.

Depending on what kind of object it is, you can either use JavaScriptObject.createObject(), or will need a static factory method to manage the creation of the object in JavaScript.

```
MyClassJSO jso = (MyClassJSO) JavaScriptObject.createObject();
```

or

```
MyClassJSO jso = JavaScriptObject.createObject().cast();
```

or

```
MyClassJSO jso = MyClassJSO.createInstance();

public static native MyClassJSO createInstance() /*-{
    return new MyObjectFromJavaScript;//or whatever you need to do 
    //in JS to create the object
}-*/;
```